# devstack installation - floating ips

Tags: openstack, devstack

i play with a multi-node devstack installation using nova-network and having quantum disabled.

my problem is that i cannot connect to a created instance in a node A from another node B of the installation

Some comments regarding the installation:

- for the fixed_ip and the floating_ip range i use two sets of private ips.
- fixed_ips seem to work and after the services are up i can see a related entry in the routing table
- floating_ips also work, meaning that they can be assigned to created instances however are not accesible from other nodes (or the same node) and no routing entry exists (or any other entry in the iptables)

should floating_ips be public ones ? why no routing entry is created for floating ips?

Answer (score 1):

Yes floating ips should be Public ones, which can be accessed from the internet.
Please check the security group and rules in attached to those instances as the default security group does not allow incoming traffic by default.

Answer (score 1):

Verify this: [Openstack VM is not accessible on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401425/openstack-vm-is-not-accessible-on-lan).

In my case I did just:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens160/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
```

#### That did my Devstack VM's visible to the world!