# DevStack instances can't be reached outside devstack node

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron, floating-ip

Following official [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/), I'm trying to deploy a `Devstack` on an `Ubuntu 18.04 Server` OS on a virtual machine. The devstack node has only one network card (ens160) connected to a network with the following CIDR `10.20.30.40/24`. I need my instances accessible publicly on this network (from 10.20.30.240 to 10.20.30.250). So again the following the official floating-IP [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/networking.html#shared-guest-interface) I managed to form this `local.conf` file:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

PUBLIC_INTERFACE=ens160
HOST_IP=10.20.30.40
FLOATING_RANGE=10.20.30.40/24
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.20.30.1
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=10.20.30.240,end=10.20.30.250
```

This would lead to form a `br-ex` with the global IP address `10.20.30.40` and secondary IP address `10.20.30.1` (The gateway already exists on the network; isn't `PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY` parameter talking about real gateway on the network?)

Now, after a successful deployment, disabling `ufw` (according to [this](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/stein/guides/neutron.html#disabling-next-generation-firewall-tools)), creating a cirros instance with proper security group for ping and ssh and attaching a floating-IP, **I only can access my instance on my devstack node, not on the whole network! Also from within the cirros instance, I cannot access the outside world (even though I can access the outside world from the devstack node)**

Afterwards, watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgQARDfVrs8) video, I modified the `local.conf` file like this:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

FLAT_INTERFACE=ens160
HOST_IP=10.20.30.40
FLOATING_RANGE=10.20.30.240/28
```

After a successful deployment and instance setup, **I still can access my instance only on devstack node and not from the outside! But the good news is that I can access the outside world from within the cirros instance**.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

**Update**

On the second configuration, checking packets on `tcpdump` while pinging the instance floating-IP, I observed that the `who-has` broadcast packet for the floating-IP of the instance reaches the devstack node from the network router; however no `is-at` reply is generated and thus ICMP packets are not routed to the devstack node and the instance.

So, with some tricks I created the response and everything works fine afterwards; but certainly this isn't solution and I imagine that the devstack should work out of the box without any tweaking and probably this is because of a misconfiguration of devstack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 days of tests, research and lecture, I found this: [Openstack VM is not accessible on LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401425/openstack-vm-is-not-accessible-on-lan)

Enter the following commands on `devstack` node:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens160/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
```

#### That'll do the trick!

Cheers!

Comment: Dear @marcio, that actually solves the problem on top of the second `local.conf`.
Thank you! 
It seems that your reputation isn't that low anymore :-D

Comment: Thank you! My reputation was low to comment and reviewers didn't let me re-post a single question. What "tricks" did you use to solve the problem?!

Comment: Look this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109557/how-to-expose-the-devstack-floating-ip-to-the-external-world/59132121#59132121